# NetSuite: An error occurred while processing item options

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am loading, doing some changes, and saving a Sales Order. I do this on approve and everything works. I do this on edit (when the status is changed to Pending Approval) and it throws the above error: 
"An error occurred while processing item options."

Now I have commented out the setting of 2 fields I was setting. It still throws the error.

The only thing that comes up in SuiteAnswers doesn't really make sense to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being caused by something else in my code that I didn't think mattered.

When status is changed to Pending Approval, I delete a record where there is a Custom field that references it on the SO line. I was deleting it, setting some values, and then saving the record. When i took the delete out, it worked. So I ended up pushing the id of the record to delete into an array and then looping over that AFTER I saved the record and it worked